# What is the EPSG code for UTM 28P?

Tags: epsg, utm, sierra-leone

I have been given some data from Sierra Leone, with coordinates collected from a GPS app which specifies UTM 28P. The standard UTMs for Sierra Leone are 28 or 29 N or So, which have corresponding EPSG codes. I can find no reference to 28 or 29P. If I transform the data to 28 or 29 N or S in QGIS and R the Eastings are c600 km to the east of where they should be and the Northings look correct.

Can anyone explain what the P means and if there is a corresponding EPSG?

Comment: 28P is a Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) designator code. It is not a UTM designation, though MGRS is constructed on top of UTM (the 28 part).

Comment: Thank you. The answer above for which my question was deemed a duplicate has answered everything for me in great detail.